# Split string in two parts: uppercase and anything else

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split a string in two parts. First part is always all uppercase and numbers. Second part can be anything.

For example:

```
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT Amet consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Should be split into

```
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT
```

and

```
Amet consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Also:

```
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT amet 0.3 consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Should be split into

```
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT
```

and

```
amet 0.3 consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Comment: Has it always two parts? If not, when does the third part start, at the first two uppercase letters?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: What characters can the first part consists of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on the following regex

```
(?<=^[A-Z0-9,\s]+)\s(?![A-Z0-9,]+\b)
```

[image]

Sample code:

```
string input = "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT Amet consectetur adipiscing elit";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=^[A-Z0-9,\s]+)\s(?![A-Z0-9,]+\b)");
foreach (string part in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(part);
```

Output:

```
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT
Amet consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Another case:

```
string input = "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT amet 0.3 consectetur adipiscing elit";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=^[A-Z0-9,\s]+)\s(?![A-Z0-9,]+\b)");
foreach (string part in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(part);
```

Output:

```
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT
amet 0.3 consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b(?=[A-Z][a-z])");
string[] result = regex.Split(yourstr, 2);
```

pattern details:

```
\b               # \b is a word boundary (limit between a member
                 # of the \w class and an other character
(?=              # open a lookahead assertion that means "followed by"
    [A-Z][a-z]   # an Uppercase and a lowercase letter
)
```

the second parameter of the split method limits the number of items.

Since you have edited your question and you want now to split at the first lowercase letter too, you can change the pattern to:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b(?=[A-Z]?[a-z])");
```

That makes the uppercase letter optional.

Note: if you want to trim potential trailing whitespaces at the end of the first substring, you can change the pattern to:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s*\b(?=[A-Z]?[a-z])");
```

Comment: I have edited the question, can review the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a split on this : `(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z]?[a-z])`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that it always consists of two parts  this simple approach could work:

```
string text = "   LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT amet 0.3 consectetur adipiscing elit";
string[] words = text.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
bool startUpper = words.First().All(Char.IsUpper);
var firstSwitchingCaseWord = words
    .Select((word, index) => new { word, index })
    .FirstOrDefault(x => startUpper ? x.word.Any(Char.IsLower) : x.word.Any(Char.IsUpper));
if (firstSwitchingCaseWord != null)
{
    string firstPart = string.Join(" ", words.Take(firstSwitchingCaseWord.index));
    string lastPart  = string.Join(" ", words.Skip(firstSwitchingCaseWord.index));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said first char should be Caps, number or sign.. Actually u have to specify the ascii if u gonna use the below one which is simple and understandable if u r confused with Regex..

currently I have done this if 1st char is Caps or Number if u wnt to add some one char u need to specify the ascii value in **`if`** condition inside the **`isFound`** method

try the below one --

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        string input = "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT Amet consectetur adipiscing elit";
        string[] arr = input.Split(' ');            
        List<string> splitList = new List<string>();
        int loc = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (isFound(arr[i]))
            {
                loc = input.IndexOf(arr[i]);
                splitList.Add(input.Substring(0, loc));
                input = input.Substring(loc);
            }
        }
        splitList.Add(input);
        //splitList is the list of splited string
     }


    static bool isFound(string str)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if ((str[0] > 64 && str[0] < 91)  ||  (str[0] > 47 && str[0] < 58))
        {
            if (str.Count(x => (x > 96 && x < 123)) > 0)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }            
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if your string is going to be splitted only on first occurrence then.

```
string pattern = "[A-Z]?[a-z]+";            
string toSplit = "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 0,5 SIT Amet consectetur adipiscing elit Atest sss";
Match match = Regex.Match(toSplit, pattern);
if (match.Success) {
     int index = match.Index;
     string splittedVal = toSplit.Substring(0, index);
     string secondPart = toSplit.Substring(index, toSplit.Length - index);
}
```